# Proof that the weighted sum of $n$ PDFs is a valid PDF

Tags: density-function, proof

Let $f_i(y)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ be valid PDF’s, and let $a_i ∈ (0, 1)$ be constants, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i= 1$.

1. Show that the function $f(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, f_i(y)$ is a valid PDF.
2. If $E [Y_i] = \mu_i$ and $\text{Var}(Y_i) = σ^2_i$, show that
   (i) $E[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, \mu_i$, 
   (ii) $E[Y^2_i] = \mu^2_i + σ^2_i$.

I understand the basic requirements for PDF's but for whatever reason I am drawing a total blank.

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is standard bookwork -- and we treat such questions differently. Please see the `self-study` [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), then edit to add the tag, and explain what you've tried and where your difficulties lie.

Comment: I've done a little formatting. Please double check it still says what you intend, especially the last part - the one labelled "(ii)" - because it was ambiguous and I took a guess about whether the $i$ was a subscript or part of the superscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for 1) and for computing $E[Y]$**:

The requirements for a function $f$ to be a valid density is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)dt=1$ and $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$. Also, two useful properties of the integral is that $$\int g(x) + h(x)dx=\int g(x)dx+\int h(x)dx,$$ and $$\int cg(x)dx=c\int g(x)dx,$$ where $h$ and $g$ are two integrable functions and $c$ is a scalar.

Let me know if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: Note that $f(t) \geq 0$ for all $t$ is also a requirement.